# Getting Embed code from Youtube Pages

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, youtube

I am using a link that returns a youtube pages HTML. From here i would like to get the id of the video or the whole youtube embed code (as i can make one from the other)

The code I have now is not working and i am unsure why, but i am only a student learning JS for the first time. The code is then to be used in a Windows 8 Application.

```
//This Contains the HTML DATA from the website.
 var str = response.responseText;
var str1 = str.search("http://www.youtube.com/embed/");
var str2 = str.search("\" frameborder=\"0");
var str3 = str2 - str1;
var ans = str.substr(str1 + 29, str3);
document.getElementById("frame1").src = "";
var n = str.split("=");
var url = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + n[1];
document.getElementById("frame1").src = url;
```

Comment: What exactly does "not working" mean? What's the behavior of that code and how does it differ from the expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The Same Origin Policy prevents the host page from seeing the content of an Iframe from a different domain. This is a security feature built into the browser to prevent cross-domain scripting attacks.